# postgres pull out multiple values in a JSON array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table where one of the columns is a JSON array. for each key there are multiple values.

So I use this query to select out the JSON

```
select  x.cola eventid, x.colb
from special_event_conflicts t
cross join lateral json_each(t.eventid) as x(cola, colb)
```

which produces

```
"525947";"{"f1":133,"f2":2428,"f3":"MULTILINESTRING((1013339.30779158 180228.160778359,1013395.51179424 180119.844273224))"}"
```

what I want is to be able to select out the f1,f2,f3 values into there own columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=83ce86554378e7739509695eaeebff9d)

The most simple way is using the `->>` operator:

```
SELECT 
    x.event_id,
    x.colb ->> 'f1' as f1,
    x.colb ->> 'f2' as f2,
    x.colb ->> 'f3' as f3
FROM <YOUR QUERY>
```